# How many percentage to randomize and how many iterations in a "what-if analysis"?

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, separation, sensitivity-analysis

I've got complete separated data as such:

```
clear
input byte(AGEatpresentation SEX) float present2 byte(SIDE LOCATION SMGRADE NIDALANEURYSMYESNO SURGYESNO COMPLETEOBLITERATIONYESNO)
48 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 1
66 2 0 0 6 4 1 0 0
59 1 0 0 4 3 0 0 0
23 2 1 0 2 1 0 0 1
49 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
65 2 1 0 2 5 1 0 1
59 2 1 0 3 3 0 0 0
43 1 0 0 7 3 0 1 1
34 2 0 1 6 4 0 0 0
22 2 1 1 1 3 0 1 1
27 1 1 1 8 3 0 0 1
51 1 0 1 7 3 0 1 1
38 2 1 1 2 3 0 0 0
44 1 1 0 3 2 0 0 1
46 2 0 0 2 4 0 1 1
24 2 1 0 8 4 0 0 1
56 1 0 0 6 4 0 0 0
10 2 0 1 7 2 0 1 1
36 1 1 0 2 1 0 0 1
45 2 1 1 3 3 1 0 0
66 2 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
37 2 0 1 7 3 0 0 1
63 2 1 0 3 1 1 0 1
58 2 1 1 3 2 0 0 1
29 2 1 1 2 3 0 1 1
21 2 1 0 1 3 0 1 1
44 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1
38 2 0 0 2 1 0 0 1
38 2 1 1 7 4 0 0 1
65 1 0 0 3 3 0 0 0
 5 2 0 1 3 1 0 0 1
28 2 0 1 6 3 0 0 0
55 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1
39 2 0 1 3 2 0 0 0
46 2 0 0 3 2 0 1 1
61 1 0 1 3 3 0 0 0
50 1 1 0 7 4 0 1 1
56 1 0 0 1 3 0 1 1
50 2 0 1 6 3 1 0 0
31 1 0 0 6 4 0 0 1
53 1 1 0 3 3 0 0 0
25 1 0 0 7 4 0 1 1
18 2 0 0 8 3 0 0 1
70 1 0 1 7 2 1 1 1
10 2 0 0 4 2 0 0 1
57 1 1 0 3 2 0 0 1
67 1 0 0 6 3 0 0 1
41 2 0 0 7 3 1 0 0
26 2 0 1 6 3 0 0 0
68 2 0 1 3 1 0 1 1
59 2 0 0 7 3 1 0 1
43 1 1 0 3 2 1 0 1
43 1 1 0 7 2 1 0 1
33 2 0 0 2 2 1 0 1
53 2 1 1 6 4 0 0 0
24 2 0 1 4 4 0 0 1
53 2 0 1 6 2 0 0 1
16 2 1 1 4 2 0 0 1
61 2 1 0 4 4 0 0 1
46 2 0 0 6 3 0 1 1
67 1 0 1 2 2 0 0 0
31 2 1 1 8 5 0 1 1
45 1 1 1 4 3 0 0 1
26 1 0 0 4 1 0 1 1
 8 2 0 1 2 1 1 0 1
59 2 0 0 4 2 0 0 1
57 1 1 0 4 4 0 0 1
36 1 1 0 4 3 0 0 1
57 2 1 0 3 4 0 0 0
40 1 1 0 8 3 0 0 0
66 1 0 0 6 3 0 0 0
15 2 0 1 2 2 0 1 1
46 2 0 0 7 3 0 1 1
65 1 0 0 7 3 0 0 0
 9 1 0 1 3 3 0 0 0
28 1 0 1 6 4 0 0 0
18 1 1 0 1 2 0 0 1
55 2 1 0 3 2 1 1 1
37 1 0 1 7 3 0 0 1
50 1 1 0 3 3 0 0 0
31 2 1 1 1 2 0 1 1
41 1 0 1 7 4 1 0 0
43 1 1 1 3 3 0 1 1
75 2 0 0 7 3 0 0 1
40 1 1 1 3 4 1 1 1
39 1 1 0 5 2 1 0 1
71 1 0 1 2 2 0 0 0
49 2 1 0 4 2 0 0 1
17 2 0 0 6 4 1 1 1
41 1 0 1 7 2 0 0 0
32 2 1 0 2 3 0 0 0
47 1 1 1 1 4 0 0 1
26 2 1 1 6 4 0 0 1
22 1 0 1 8 3 0 1 1
20 1 0 1 6 3 0 0 0
11 2 0 1 3 1 0 0 1
42 2 1 0 2 3 0 1 1
53 2 0 1 7 2 0 1 1
35 2 1 0 2 2 0 0 0
54 2 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
end
```

My outcome is `COMPLETEOBLITERATION` and the rest are predictors in a multiple logistic regression. Notice that `SURGYESNO` is completely separated and will not be included in said model as a result!

I've decided to combat this problem, that I will assign a certain % of `SURGYESNO` to the opposite value (what-if analysis), to see if it still predicts. It does with 10% randomization, however how do I know that 10% is the right number? Furthermore, how many iterations should I run before I can statistically be assured that my results are correct? Lastly, how do I compare the results of the iterations, do I just mean out the p-values and coefficients?

I ask because obviously the values change for each time I load the data and randomly assign 10%. Should I perhaps only do this ONCE and never look at it again? It sounds more robust to do many iterations and average them out?

Thank you!